# SQL : How can i join different tables from competition of football?

Tags: sql, postgresql

**The problem**

I have to make a SQL (postgres) query, to show the names of players, whose teams participate in the "Primeira Liga" and the "Taça de Portugal". Also, include the names of players of "Académica" club and all of teams founded in the 1940s.
[Image of Database design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsJUD.png)

I'm really stuck and can't figure out, how to connect all tables. Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

**Updated** (10/01/2021):
** I had to change the names to match my DB, so everyone can understand.

[image: DB]

Comment: Welcome to Stack, what would be helpful is to see some sample data for each of the tables and what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: Can you give some example records and how you know a team is manchester united ? Also how would you know whether a competition is from "Premier League"? Btw, i would suggest renaming id in the respective tables as team.team_id and competiotion.competition_id.

Comment: The first question is a relational division question, see for example Joe Celko [Divided We Stand: The SQL of Relational Division](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) who writes about various methods to solve this. @DrPhil That's more of a personal style choice than anything. I would be much more concerned about renaming `player.nome` to `name`

Comment: I notice there is no date data for the when a player was in a team. Does it matter if the player was not in the team when the team played in the "Premier League" and the "National Cup"?

Comment: @SimonR i added a picture of data on DB. What i want to achieve is: to extract the  names of players, whose teams participate both in the "Primeira Liga" and the "Taça de Portugal". Also, include every team founded in 40s.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT DISTINCT j.nome 
FROM jogador as j 
INNER JOIN equipa as E 
ON E.id = j.equipa_id 
INNER JOIN competicao_equipa as eq 
ON E.id = eq.equipa_id 
WHERE (eq.competicao_id = 1 OR eq.competicao_id = 3))

UNION 

(SELECT j.nome
FROM jogador as j
where equipa_id = 1)

UNION

(SELECT j.nome
FROM jogador as j,equipa
where equipa.fundacao BETWEEN '01/01/1940' AND '31/12/1949')
```

Comment: i read this site: https://learnsql.com/blog/how-to-join-3-tables-or-more-in-sql/  and understood the concept. good read